# How to change the package name in " Spring 3 MVC Login Form Example" in RoseIndia.com?

Tags: java, spring, package

I am new to the spring framework, and I just followed the  ["Spring 3 MVC Login Form Example" in RoseIndia.com.](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/spring-3-mvc-login-example.html) And first time I changed package name:`net.roseindia.controllers` to `login.controllers` and also `net.roseindia.form` to `login.form`, and also updated all the related code in these two packages classes and `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, but then the problem is, when I run `index.jsp` and click the "Login form", it should go to`http://localhost:8086/Spring3Example/forms/loginform.html` which is generated by `loginform.jsp` in the "views" folder, but it didn't work and shows `HTTP Status 404`.
And then I also tried to change **net.roseindia.controllers to net.login.controllers and 
net.roseindia.form to net.login.form**, didn't work neither. 
Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: what does build successful mean? i guess there must be some hidden configuration related to the package name, now i tried again, it will work if i only change net.roseindia.form to net.login.form, but still can't change net.roseindia.controllers to net.login.controllers.

Comment: Don't follow the roseindia tutorials, they're terrible, inaccurate and usually wrong.

Answer (score 2):

*First I have to aggree with skaffman: "Don't follow the roseindia tutorials, they're terrible, inaccurate and usually wrong." Especially in this case: Do not implement your own security stuff, use [spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) instead.*

I did not check that the tutorial is working with the original code. I hope you did it before changing the names!

Anyway what you described looks like you changed the dispatcher servlet mapping. The tutorial needs that the dispatcher url pattern is `/forms/*`

```
<servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/forms/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

A second thing that may have gone wrong is, that the application does not start at all. So check your server log files and make sure that the application starts without any exception.

Comment: Ralph: i didn't change the dispatcher, and the example did work before i change the package name,

Comment: @user1055108: does the server start correct? And is deployed under the name `Spring3Example`?

Comment: yes, the server start correct and  deployed under the name Spring3Example